# Exchange Online - Powershell cmdlet "New-MailboxImportRequest" not accepting "FilePath" parameter

Tags: powershell, office365

When I am using the cmdlet New-MailboxImportRequest, it is not accepting the -FilePath parameter.  And when I remove the parameter it complains that it is required!  I'm sure there is a quick explanation for this.  Any ideas?

Some details:

- PowerShell version 6.2.1(also tried in PowerShell 5.1)
- Connecting to O365 using URI https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/
- I have given myself the "Mailbox Import Export" role necessary for running this cmdlet.
- I am able to run Get-MailboxImportRequest without issue

With FilePath it complains:

```
PS C:\> New-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox "Archive Mailbox" -FilePath "D:\testuser.pst" -TargetRootFolder "RecoveredFiles" -IncludeFolders "#Inbox#"
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FilePath'.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-MailboxImportRequest], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,New-MailboxImportRequest
+ PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Without FilePath it complains:

```
PS C:\> New-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox "Archive Mailbox" -TargetRootFolder "RecoveredFiles" -IncludeFolders "#Inbox#"
Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: FilePath.
At C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_n11tq1ct.qbd\tmp_n11tq1ct.qbd.psm1:44229 char:9
+         $steppablePipeline.End()
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-MailboxImportRequest], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingMandatoryParameter,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Migration.MailboxReplication.MailboxImportRequest.NewMailboxImportRequest
```

EDIT: I re-read the Microsoft documentation and noticed that for "FilePath" it states that "This parameter is available only in on-premises Exchange."  Which makes this even more confusing.  If its only available in on-prem, why is it a required parameter for Exchange Online?  If it's not a valid parameter for Exchange Online, why even have this PowerShell command available in EXO?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/new-mailboximportrequest?view=exchange-ps

Comment: May or may not be related. From my fuzzy-long-time ago memory, this cmdlet requires a UNC path, a local path won't make it happy.

Comment: Thanks for that idea.  I created a directory, shared it, restarted my powershell session and tried using the UNC path to that share and it still gave the same error.  I confirmed the UNC path in the windows file explorer to make sure I was entering the path correctly.

Comment: one possible source of such an error is an embedded invalid character - an  `em-dash` instead of a `hyphen` is one such case. try saving your command line as text and then feeding it to `Format-Hex` so that you can check the characters in the string.

Comment: Thanks.  I retyped the command by hand multiple times(to ensure no invalid characters) and still the same result.

Comment: @WilliamOettmeier - i'm out of ideas .. i will go back to lurking. however, you likely otta add that info to your Original Post so others will find it. [*grin*]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/new-mailboximportrequest?view=exchange-ps Check this help document, `-FilePath This parameter is available only in on-premises Exchange`.

Comment: Thanks.  I added that as an edit to my question yesterday, towards the bottom.  Which leaves the philosophical question: if that parameter is only valid for on-prem Exchange, why is it an EXO commandlet?  What use is the commandlet for EXO without that parameter?